# pytest: running in threading

Tags: python, multithreading, pytest

A python file named pytest_demo.py:

```
import pytest
import threading

@pytest.mark.test
class TestDemo():
    def test_demo_false(self):
        assert False

    def test_demo_true(self):
        assert True

    def test_demo_thread_true(self):
        thread1 = MyThread(True)
        thread1.start()

    def test_demo_thread_false(self):
        thread1 = MyThread(False)
        thread1.start()


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, flag):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.flag = flag

    def run(self):
        print "Starting "
        assert self.flag


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main(['-v', '-m', 'test', 'pytest_demo.py'])
```

The output is after run " python pytest_demo.py":

```
pytest_demo.py:8: TestDemo.test_demo_false FAILED
pytest_demo.py:11: TestDemo.test_demo_true PASSED
pytest_demo.py:14: TestDemo.test_demo_thread_true PASSED
pytest_demo.py:18: TestDemo.test_demo_thread_false PASSED
```

in thread, why the TestDemo.test_demo_thread_false is PASSED?

Answer (score 10):

Because the AssertionError gets raised in a separate thread.
Your `test_demo_thread_false` method doesn't assert anything, it just spawns a new thread, and it always does that successfully.

Comment: basically: why do you need to assert in a thread? Your unit-tests should test your methods in the same thread. Your integration tests can spawn off as many threads as they like, but you should be testing the system as a whole (you don't care if the logic was in a separate thread, all you care is a certain global state is reached)

Comment: FWIW, I arrived at this question wondering how to run expensive-but-unrelated test cases in parallel.  Perhaps OP was trying to build a simple version of that,

Comment: @EdBrannin indeed, perhaps that's what they wanted. BTW have you checked out https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-xdist for running tests in parallel? Haven't used it myself but it looks promising.

Comment: I'm looking at it now, trying to figure out if/how I can prevent certain tests from running simultaneously (the main page doesn't say anything about synchronizing/locks/semaphores).

Comment: The answer, as of January 2017: No fine-gained control of test parallelism quite yet.  https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/issues/18